# custom cakephp error messages not showing

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, custom-error-pages

I have created a custom page for error messages in my web application.

I have created these two files in the views/errors/ directory named 'missing_action.ctp' and 'missing_controller.ctp'.

On **server** the error message is shown as follows:

[image]

and on **localhost** the error is shown properly like as follows:
[image]

I want to show the error messages exactly as that of on localhost but it is not appearing on server. What can be the problem.?

Comment: Is it safe to assume those file were put in the app/ directory? Is the code EXACTLY the same on both installations? CakePHP might have cached the previous page. Make sure your debug value is set to 1 or 2 in app/config/core.php to disable caching.

Comment: @placer14: thanks, your debug idea solved the problem. Please post it as the answer so that others also benefit from your answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glad this worked out for you. :)

Is it safe to assume those file were put in the app/ directory? Is the code EXACTLY the same on both installations?

**Something to remember:** CakePHP might have cached the previous page. Make sure your debug value is set to 1 or 2 in app/config/core.php to disable caching.